# Why does sd() compute an incorrect standard deviation (stddev)?

Tags: r

So I noticed a discrepancy while computing a vol, i.e. standard deviation. I manually computed it as follows:

```
v <- c(9, 2, 5, 4, 12, 7, 8, 11, 9, 3, 7, 4, 12, 5, 4, 10, 9, 6, 9, 4)
sqrt(sum((v - mean(v))^ 2) / length(v))
[1] 2.983287
```

Now if I try sd():

```
sd(v)
[1] 3.060788
```

It seems that what `sd()` is doing is:

```
sqrt(sum((v - mean(v))^ 2) / (length(v)-1))
[1] 3.060788
```

Why is it doing N - 1 for the denominator? The definition of `stddev` as I have always learned it specifies to use N as the denominator. What am I missing?

Comment: You are mixing up population vs sample sd. Sample sd uses N-1

Comment: can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54/why-do-us-and-uk-schools-teach-different-methods-of-calculating-the-standard-dev and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/sample-standard-deviation-vs-population-standard-deviation